# Syntax error of SQL insert statement in access

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, syntax, insert

I am working in a form design in which, I want the users choose purchase items from combo boxes and type the unitprice and purchase quantity. All the information selected and typed by user will be added to another table. Here I use Do Until Loop to add purchase records one by one. I tried the Do Until Loop. It works well. However, as I wrapped up, this loop with Insert Into statement I received a syntax error. Please help me to check where is the problem. Thanks.

My code:

```
Private Sub Command133_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do Until IsNull(Me.Controls("cboPurchaseItem" & i))
  Dim StrSql As String
    StrSql = "Insert Into test2 (PurchaseID,
                                PurchaseDate, 
                                ExpectedDeliveryDate, 
                                Supplier, 
                                PurchaseItem,
                                Unit, 
                                PurchaseQuantity, 
                                UnitCost, 
                                OrderStatus,)" & _
            " VALUES('" & Me!txtOrderID & "',
                     #" & Format(Me!txtOrderDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#,
                     #" & Format(Me!txtDeliveryDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#,
                    '" & Me!cboSupplierCompany & "', 
                    '" & Me.Controls("cboPurchaseItem" & i) & "', 
                    '" & Me.Controls("txtUnit" & i) & "',
                    " & CStr(Me.Controls("TxtQty" & i)) & ",
                    " & CStr(Me.Controls("TxtPrice" & i)) & ",
                    'Ordered')"
    CurrentDb.Execute (StrSql)
MsgBox " You have successfully added " & i & " records to the PurchaseOrderDetail table."
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I found one error. an additional comma "," was wrongly typed after OrderStatus. it is this couse the error message. To my surprise, data in Me!cboSupplierCompany and Me.Controls("cboPurchaseItem" & i)  can not add to the table where it show blank.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a parameterized SQL query (a best practice in modern programming) using a querydef object which avoids the need for quotes or numerals to enclose values. Simply add the `PARAMETERS` clause at top of string statement then bind values iteratively in loop.

As for the combo boxes that fail when blank, possibly it is due to the VBA nullstring that cannot be passed as string literal in query. To resolve, try using the [Nz()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function to return a zero-length string value when combo boxes are empty.

```vb
Dim qdef As Querydef
Dim i As Integer: i = 1 
Dim StrSql As String

' PREPARE SQL STATEMENT '
StrSql = "PARAMETERS [PIDParam] Integer, [PDateParam] Datetime," _
           & " [EDDateParam] Datetime, [SupplierParam] Text(255)," _
           & " [PItemParam] Text(255), [UnitParam] Text(255), [PQtyParam] Long," _
           & " [UnitCostParam] Double, [OrderStatusParam] Text(255);" _
           & " INSERT INTO test2 (PurchaseID, PurchaseDate," _
           & "                    ExpectedDeliveryDate, Supplier, PurchaseItem, Unit," _
           & "                    PurchaseQuantity, UnitCost, OrderStatus)" _
           & " VALUES ([PIDParam], [PDateParam], [EDDateParam]," _
           & "         [SupplierParam], [PItemParam], [UnitParam], [PQtyParam]," _
           & "         [UnitCostParam], [OrderStatus]);"

Do Until IsNull(Me.Controls("cboPurchaseItem" & i)) 
     ' INITIALIZE QDEF '
     Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQyerydef("", StrSqL)

     ' BIND PARAMETERS TO STATEMENT '
     qdef!PIDParam = Me!txtOrderID
     qdef!PDateParam = Me!txtOrderDate
     qdef!EDDatePram = Me!txtDeliveryDate
     qdef!SuppierPram = Nz(Me!cboSupplierCompany)
     qdef!PItemParam = Nz(Me.Controls("cboPurchaseItem" & i))
     qdef!UnitParam = Me.Controls("txtUnit" & i)
     qdef!PQtyParam = CStr(Me.Controls("TxtQty" & i))
     qdef!UnitCostParam = CStr(Me.Controls("TxtPrice" & i))
     qdef!OrderStatusParam = "Ordered"

    ' EXECUTE APPEND QUERY '
     qdef!Execute dbFailOnError
     i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox "You have successfully added " & i _
         & " records to the PurchaseOrderDetail table.", vbInformation, "APPEND SUCCESS"

Set qdef = Nothing
```